# After creating an A DNS record for WWW is it also necessary to create a AAAA record for WWW?

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

I'm using an A DNS record to translate WWW for IPV4 traffic.  It looks like this:

DNS records

TYPE: A

HOSTNAME: *www.mywebsite.example*

VALUE: directs to *192.168.0.1*

Do I need to add an AAAA record for WWW to support IPv6 traffic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer the question in your headline:

No, it is not necessary to create an AAAA record for your website as long as most traffic runs over IPv4, but I would argue that it probably is beneficial for the deployment of IPv6 to have more sites support the protocol.

To answer the question in your post:

Yes, if you want your site to support IPv6 traffic, clients need a way to translate your domain name to an IPv6 address.

Comment: Wow you're right I forgot to include WWW in my post.  But yes I meant it like the headline.  Awesome I'll add the AAAA for WWW in my DNS Records.

Comment: "I would argue that it probably is beneficial for the deployment of IPv6 to have more sites support the protocol." So the problem is not publishing the `AAAA` record that needs to come last. The first problem is to make sure the website is indeed reachable over IPv6, which, sadely, is still not always true in 2020. If the hoster says it is and provide the IPv6 address then you should add the `AAAA` record. If not, and you want IPv6 reachability, you will probably need to change your webhosting company.